# How to show that every closed subset of $\mathbb R $ containing $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R $ itself?

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem with an exercise.

The exercise is if given the usual topology on $\mathbb R.$

Suppose $ A $ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ containing all rational numbers. 
Show that $A =\mathbb R.$

But I can't find a way to prove it

Comment: First, the subject of your post is not really related to the question. Second, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you know a definition of "closed set" involving limit points?

Comment: You should give some context. Do you know $\bar{\mathbb Q} =\mathbb R $?

Comment: That is the formulation I was given.. hence to " How to show that every closed subset of RR containing QQ is RR itself? " That was not what i wrote ??

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $U\cap\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset$, then $U=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, so $\forall B\subset\mathbb R \ open \ B\cap\mathbb Q\neq\emptyset$. Consider than $B=\mathbb R\smallsetminus A$...

Comment: We can't use that Q is dense yet -_-

Comment: Ahah so this proof would be a little bit "illegal"...